# Dynamic table with razor

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

hello I have a question following the advice of you [Razor View dynamic table rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198549/razor-view-dynamic-table-rows/63386928#63386928), I made my table with foreach but not and could manage to make you create new columns, if I add a record is put in the same column, does not make a jump for another column, What can I do in this case? So I have my view on razor

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            @foreach (var item in product)
            {
                <td>
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem; margin-top:3rem; margin-right:3rem; margin-bottom:2rem; margin-left:3rem; position:initial">
                        <img src="https://scontent.fntr8-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/107865247_704094323779323_2201784036865521556_n.jpg?_nc_cat=101&_nc_sid=8bfeb9&_nc_ohc=FwSgbE0cEAAAX92rcFt&_nc_ht=scontent.fntr8-1.fna&oh=4ec8b36ac7d0080b2f2bb3096b7b38cc&oe=5F37D400" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h2 class="card-title">@item.ProductName</h2>
                            <p class="card-text">@item.Description</p>
                            <h4 class="card-text">Stock</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">@item.UnitInStock</p>
                            <h4 class="card-text">Color</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">@item.Color</p>
                            <h3 class="card-text" style="align-content:center">$@item.Price</h3>
                            <p class="card-text">@item.CreationDate.ToShortDateString()</p>
                            <AuthorizeView>
                                <Authorized>
                                    <a href="editproduct/@item.Id" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</a>
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="@(() => EliminarProduct(item.Id))">Eliminar</button>
                                </Authorized>
                                <NotAuthorized>

                                </NotAuthorized>
                            </AuthorizeView>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                count++;
                if (count % 3 == 0)
                {
                    @:</tr>
                    @:<tr>
                }
            }
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a bit of difficulty understanding your question; I am sure you are doing your best to explain your problem.
So excuse me if this does not answer your question.

I think I see what you are trying to do there; placing 3 blocks in a row then followed by 3 other blocks.

One of the problems I foresee is that when you have exactly `%3` items (so you have for instance 6 items), the last one will add a  to your html and then the loop will end and add one more . So rather than checking `%3` you should also check if you aren't at the last item; So something like this

```
if (count % 3 == 0 && count != product.Count())
```

May I make a suggestion that you use divs instead of a table? Just generate a div for each block and use css to style them. Depending on your solution you could even number your divs with a different class name (like: class1, class2, class3) and give them each a specific css or you could add `float: left` to each div and add `clear: both;` to the first one in your row.

The best way however would be using css where you would place any number of objects on a row as much as the width of the page permits you.

One more thing; if you want to list items in blazor it is wise to add the @key tag to each div or tr.

Comment: An apology if the question is not well structured, which would be I want to have a column with three elements and that the mometo to generate another product this is added in a new column and thus itsesively, that columns of three elements are generated